# "В своей именной церкви Пракседа изображена..." - возможно ли такое?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> В конхе апсиды своей именной церкви Пракседа изображена в диадеме и
>   одеждах земной – византийской – царицы. Она стоит по правую руку от
>   Христа и сжимает венец жизни Вечной.
>
> ---

[Базилика Святой Пракседы — Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B)

> Базилика Санта-Прасседе (итал. Santa Prassede) — римская титулярная
>   церковь во имя святой Пракседы, находящаяся на Эсквилинском холме.

Answer (score 1):

Своя (даже ее) церковь - скорее принадлежащая ей или та, где она находится сейчас. Может, она там похоронена? В противном случае: церковь ее имени.

**В конхе апсиды, находящейся (расположенной) в церкови ее имени, Пракседа изображена...**

Comment: Так у меня автор и заменил часто встечающееся в тексте сочетание  *церковь во имя святой Пракседы* на *своей именной церкви*. Вышел из положения.